# jQuery UI Accordion - Close all if Not On "Active Page"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using the jQuery UI Accordion with the navigation: true toggled. With that, URL's in the accordion determine which accordion portion is opened. If it doesn't match a URL, is there a way to have it close all accordions by default? I've got collapsible set to true.

```
    $( "#sidebarNav" ).accordion({ event: 'mouseover', autoHeight: false, navigation: true, collapsible: true });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the accordion options, try

```
active: false
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but then the navigation: true no longer works.